# A More precise PNG library for .NET 2.0?

Tags: c#, encoding, png

Yes, I am using C# 2.0 and need to do things with PNG files, for example use a custom palette, that I cannot find out how to do with System.Drawing.

Is there a 3rd-party library (preferably GPL-compatible) that will enable more fine-tuned control over PNG encoding?

**Update:** Examples of what I want to do:

- Create, edit, and remove an image's pallete (removing a pallete involves changing the color space).
- Add or edit text chunks (iTXt, tEXt, and zTXt).
- Add or edit other miscellaneous chunks (like bKGD and sPLT).

Comment: Can you be more specific about the kinds of things you need to do?

Answer (score 2):

I've had success with [FreeImage.NET](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/download.html) and [Mono.Cairo](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono.Cairo).

Comment: I can't seem to find a download link for FreeImage.NET.