# Native .NET PNG image file encoder

Tags: .net, gdi+, png, imaging

Does such an encoder exist?  The GDI+ one is not very fully featured.  For example, it will always render out 32bpp images, even if you're using 8bpp indexed in-memory.

I'm about to start writing out a lot of PNGs from a web server that should really be 8bpp indexed with transparency (PNG supports alpha levels in the palette).  I want to do this with native .NET (and unsafe code) for performance reasons, so please don't suggest [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) or [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/).

The longer this question goes unanswered, the further through the [PNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/) I will have read :)

Comment: Using a library written in c with p-invoke should rather be faster than writing in in C#. How about just p-invoking LibPNG? IMO the only reason to use C# is getting verifiable IL code that can run in low trust scenarios such as silverlight.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A More precise PNG library for .NET 2.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360445/a-more-precise-png-library-for-net-2-0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the PngBitmapEncoder class, it uses WIC under the covers.  The FormatConvertedBitmap class helps you set the palette and make the pixel format conversion.  At least .NET 3.0 required.

Comment: thanks very much.  The `PngBitmapEncoder` works quite well for what I want, though it's a shame I have to reference half of WPF in my ASP.NET program.  Also, the `Save` method requires a seekable stream (as far as I can tell) so I have to write the file to a throw-away `MemoryStream` and then copy it out to the HTTP response stream.  It'd be nice to avoid that memory churn.  Still, I'm seeing a nice heat-map layer on Google Maps now.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You could also check out nQuant at http://nquant.codeplex.com. If you pass your GDI+ 32bit BitMap instance to it, it will return an 8bit 256 color indexed paelette image. If the original image was 8 bit, this conversion should be lossless.

This is a vanilla C# written library with no dependencies.